# Moving Jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

So I have been asked to create a job on a Jenkins system that is on the university servers. The problem is I was asked to create it in a specific folder. However I accidentally created in the root folder. Is there a way to move the job from the root to the specific folder or do I have to delete it and create a new one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move jenkins job to sub folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406546/how-to-move-jenkins-job-to-sub-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your job's configuration page and from 'Advanced Project Options' check 'Use custom workspace'. Enter the path of the directory where you want the files to be created.

Answer (score 1):

There is a move option on the GUI:
Stand on the little triangle near the job you want to move/copy/delete, and on the popup menu - choose the wanted operation. On move you can move to another folder.
But, There is also an open issue about this (opened on 2016):
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35093
I had to restart Jenkins after doing it to a job with some history.

So maybe re-create/copy and delete is a better solution (but no history is saved).