# How to move jenkins job to sub folder?

Tags: jenkins

I have 10 jenkins job in folder `foo`. I have created a new sub folder `baar` in folder `foo`. How to move the 10 jobs from folder `foo` to the subfolder `baar`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, you need to install [cloudbees folder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) then you will see  Move option in jobs

[image]

click on it,then option(drop down) will come where you want to move [image]

select and move

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that the "Move" option is only displayed when at least one folder exist on the server.

Comment: Where do you mean by server? I can't find the move option too.

Comment: Now I know what you mean, we have to create it from Jenkin's New Item option.

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple jobs and move them all to the same folder?

Answer (score 13):

As @Pratik Anand mentionned you will first need to install the [CloudBees Folders Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin).

However, if you want to move many projects at the same time, it is much faster to do it with the [script console](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console). This groovy script does the trick :

```
def FOLDER_NAME = '<An existing destination folder>'
def JOB_REGEX = '<A regex to find your jobs>'

import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

jenkins = Jenkins.instance

def folder = jenkins.getItemByFullName(FOLDER_NAME)
if (folder == null) {
  println "ERROR: Folder '$FOLDER_NAME' not found"
  return
}

// Find jobs in main folder
def found = jenkins.items.grep { it.name =~ "${JOB_REGEX}" }
println "Searching main folder : $found"

// Find jobs in other subfolders
jenkins.items.grep { it instanceof com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder }.each { subfolder -> 
  if(!subfolder.getName().equals(FOLDER_NAME))
  {
    println "Searching folder '$subfolder.name'"
    subfolder.getItems().grep { it.name =~ "${JOB_REGEX}" }.each { job ->
      println "Found $job.name"
      found.add(job);
    }
  }
}

// Move them
found.each { job ->
  println "Moving '$job.name' to '$folder.name'"
  Items.move(job, folder)
}
```

I used Daniel Serodio's reply in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/doYddgacqTQ) and modified it to search subfolders also. Note that this is not fully recursive.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer, it`s **great solution**!

Comment: In the last line "Items.move(...)" what is Items? I don't see it defined anywhere? In my case I just want to move 1 job to a folder.

Comment: @Chris F `hudson.model.Items` 
You can see the details in the Jenkins javadoc: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/ 

However, if you only want to move one job, using the CloudBees Folders plugin directly is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If your jobs are written in DSL, you can create a folder thus:

```
folder("foo") {
  displayName('foo')
  description('A folder with all my foo')
}

folder("baar") {
  displayName('baar')
  description('A folder with all my baar')
}
```

Then, in your dsl for your jobs, you simply have to reference that folder in the job creation:

```
job('baar/myJob') {
  description('A job which now lives in the baar folder.')
  ...
}
```

Once the DSL plugin processes your job you will see it in that folder.  However, the folder has to already exist, so I generally name my folder DSL something like `all_folders.groovy` so it gets processed first.  If you don't specify a folder in the `job` declaration it will be in the main Jenkins view.

Comment: When I try to do this, I end up with two pipelines, the old one and the new one

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the plugin folder ?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin

You can then move the jobs with the function: "move"